# AngularJS RouteProvider Single When-Condition For All Route/Path/URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, route-provider

I'm using $routeProvider to change a page (telmplate) and controller when user click a link.

Like this:

```
$routeProvider.when('/profile/', {
        templateUrl: '/app/views/profile.html',     
        controller: 'ProfileCtrl'
    }).when('/timeline/', {
        templateUrl: '/app/views/timeline.html',        
        controller: 'TimelineCtrl'
    }).when('/chat/:username', {
        templateUrl: function(param){
          if(param){
            return '/app/views/chat.html?' + param; 
          }
           return '/';
        },      
        controller: 'ChatCtrl'
    }).otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
```

The problem is there are so many pages on my app and I need to register every single url on `.when` condition repetitively, whereas the template url and controller name is loaded based on link path.

My question is: Can I generalized all those when condition into a single when statement?

Like this:

```
$routeProvider.when(url, {
    templateUrl: '/app/views/' + url + '.html',     
       controller: url + 'Ctrl'
});
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you try to generate routes from url list inside loop?

Comment: No, I want to have a general routing condition to load the templateurl and controller name by given path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like below:

```
angular.module('myapp', ['myapp.filters', 'myapp.services', 'myapp.directives']).
    config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/page/:name', {
        templateUrl: function(urlattr){
            return '/pages/' + urlattr.name + '.html';
        },
        controller: urlattr.name+'Ctrl.js'
      });
     }
]);
```

Please try it. In this case I am assuming your html page name is same as Controller name and have 'Ctrl' as suffix.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Btw, on your example the controller loaded from a .js file. Can it be done? Because all this time I have to put my all controller inside one .js file. I'm sorry this is OOT, I'm noob in Angular

Comment: Yes, you can have all controllers in single js file or each controller as a separate js file, depends on architecture of your project. If you have every controller in separate js, make sure your register it with your app name, and include it in index.html